# How to get the pixel value of an image in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I have an image of segmented cells. Each segmented cell is represented as an integer which is its label. Is it possible to get the pixel value of a segmented cell by clicking inside it and possibly change this value?

Here is an example image:

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "segmented cells". Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added a sample image.

Comment: So it sounds like the concept of "segmented cells" is not really important, and all you want is to be able to get the clicked pixel's RGBA value and to be able to draw on the image. Is that correct?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Yes, I want to get the value and change it to something else.